# Alternatives to redmine/gitlab/gerrit

Tags: git, redmine, gitlab

Are there any decent alternatives to redmine/gitlab/gerrit for git project hosting where the repository is actually created when the project is created?

Comment: Hi Nigel. Please read the StackOverflow [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about what makes a good question on Stack Overflow. Your question is very subjective (some people might like redmine/gitlab/gerrit, or have found an alternative that is "decent" to them, but not to others). Questions like these are best asked on forums, chat rooms, mailing lists, or other places that are considered for more "general" conversation. StackOverflow tries to concentrate on objective questions only.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the case you did not know - Redmine can create Git repository on project creation with help of the [SCM Creator](http://projects.andriylesyuk.com/projects/scm-creator).